# Unable to paste text into textfield from clipboard history in flutter desktop

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-debug

I'm trying to paste text from the clipboard history into the textfield on flutter desktop but it's not working in new updates. It was working fine in the previous updates of flutter. could you please guide me how can i solve this issue? moreover, there is no exception and theming i've applied

[image]

Previously, when i click on the text from the clipboard the text will be pasted into the textfield but now in the latest updates it's not working.

Comment: your flutter version?

Comment: [√] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.19.0, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.22631.3155], locale en-US)